# iOS Clean Bad XML

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

Sometimes we receive incorrect `XML` back from a web service. Are there any libraries out there for `objective-c`, and specifically for `iOS` that can clean up XML to make it valid for a parser? Something like `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` but for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML), specifically `CXMLDocumentTidyXML`. Being a JSON fan myself, I've never used it, but it seems to be capable of tidying up xml. You would do something like this:

```
CXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<foo></bar>" 
                                                       options:CXMLDocumentTidyXML
                                                         error:&theError];
```